# String formatting in Python for today standards

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting, string-formatting

i'm learning python from a book that i bought in 2017 and from a online course at the same time.

The book says that i should format the string like this example;

```
print("Guess number %d of %d" % (variable1, variable2))
```

But the online course says that i should format this way;

```
print("Guess number {} of {}".format(variable1, variable2))
```

Which one should i use for today programming standards?

Answer (score 4):

Well, from Python 3.6, you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
print(f"Guess number {variable1} of {variable2}")
```

Comment: curiosity.  There is one other major difference too, isn’t there?  an f-string is built and replaced on the spot, with local variables.  whereas a %-based, or a $-based, template can be saved and used elsewhere/later.  I ask that because I have code that relies heavily on building complex templates and passing them around as parameters.  So I’ve always seen f-strings as nice (and fast) but not always flexible enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd predict the use are f-strings are aimed at readability. That said, i would say the real answer is which ever one is more readable in your function or whatever.